# How can I inherit contact on github?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

there is a contract on github. I need to inherit it/ So how can I do it? Using import isn't available how I unnderstand..

https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just import from the GitHub link, but in your case there is an nom package containing that contract already so you could:

1. Run `npm i @uniswap/v2-periphery` on your project.
2. Import it like this on your .sol file: `import '@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol';`

Answer (score 1):

Good Day

One Can Do the Following below your pragma statement

Add The Following

```
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol";
```

Or

```
import '@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol';
```

above your constructor declare the following

```
 address public routerContract;
```

in the Constructor you can do the following

```
 constructor(address routerContractAddr){
        routerContract= routerContractAddr;
    }
```

in order to use the interface functions one can do the following

```
IUniswapV2Router01(routerContract).swapExactTokensForTokens(....);
```

remember to deploy your contract with the correct `Uniswap` Router Address

an example of a deploy script using hardhat is illustrated below

```
 module.exports = async ({ ethers, getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deploy } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  await deploy("YourContract", {
    from: deployer,
    args: ["UNISWAP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS"],
    deterministicDeployment: false,
    log: true,
  });
 
};

module.exports.tags = ["YourContract"];
```

I Really Hope That My Answer Provides Clarity

Thank You